# The view products.views.get_product didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, valueerror

ValueError at /product/apple-ipad-air-5th-gen-64-gb-rom-109-inch-with-wi-fi5g-purple/
The view products.views.get_product didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

how can i solve this problem please help me
`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from products.models import Product
from accounts.models import *
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from products.models import *
from django.utils.timezone import datetime
# Create your views here.

def get_product(request, slug):
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    # comment = Comment.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == "POST":
        star = request.POST.get('star')
        name = request.user.first_name
        body = request.POST.get('body')
        review = Comment(star=star, name=name,body=body,date_added = datetime.today())
        review.product = product
        review.save()
        return redirect(f'/product/{slug}', slug=product.slug)

    try:
        context = {'product': product, }
        if request.GET.get('size'):
            size = request.GET.get('size')
            price = product.get_product_price_by_size(size)
            context['selected_size'] = size
            context['updated_price'] = price
        return render(request, 'product\product.html' , context = context)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

`

i am making a ecommerce website and i add review option then i got this error

Comment: There is no return in the `except` block. Maybe return the exception or one without a message like `return HttpResponse(status=500)` to show it in HTML.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because `return` is inside if statement.

I have modified this:

```
    try:
        context = {'product': product, }
        if request.GET.get('size'):
            size = request.GET.get('size')
            price = product.get_product_price_by_size(size)
            context['selected_size'] = size
            context['updated_price'] = price
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return render(request, 'product\product.html', context)
```